# Extract all lines between two patterns, containing at least one occurence of one string

Tags: linux, bash, awk, sed

I have a large file stored in a bash variable as a string, and i need to extract all the lines between two same words. But I also need to check if between these lines, I have at least one occurence of `magicstring`. Here's an example :

```
abc
xxxxxxxx
yyyyyyyy

abc
magicstring
kkkkkkkk
magicstring

abc
mmmmmmmm
nnnnnnnn
```

What I am looking for is the following :

```
magicstring
kkkkkkkk
magicstring
```

The two same words are always `abc`, but using sed, awk or even parameter expansion, how could I precise that I need the word `magicstring` contained at least once in those lines ?

I am assuming that I don't know the section where `magicstring` is contained, since it's a large file.
EDIT : Also, `magicstring` appears only once or multiple times in only one section.

Using sed for example, I would get all the lines like this : `sed '/abc/,/abc/{//!d}' <<<($myFileInVar)` but I don't know to precise the need of `magicstring`.

Comment: In my point of view all lines except the two last ones are between `abc` lines. Is that your understanding too? If yes, then you need to explain why you removed a the blank line from the output. And putting your file in a variable just makes your life harder, do not do it. Use `sed ... file`.

Comment: `I have a large file stored in a bash variable as a string` is a bad starting point for anything.

Answer (score 1):

`gawk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk -v RS='(^|\n)abc\n' '/magicstring/' file

magicstring
kkkkkkkk
magicstring
```

define the delimiter word as the record separator, print the record if it matches the magic string.

Answer (score 1):

Using any awk in any shell on every UNIX box:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/magicstring/' file
abc
magicstring
kkkkkkkk
magicstring

$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '/magicstring/{sub(/^[^\n]+\n/,""); print}' file
magicstring
kkkkkkkk
magicstring
```